# 'FixedHeaderTableLayout' giving warning 'unfortunately touchwiz home has stopped' in API Level 14 Samsung Device

Tags: android-tablelayout

Any solution or suggestion, please recommend. What is the minimum API level for using this repohttps://github.com/Zardozz/FixedHeaderTableLayout?

Answer (score 0):

The [Readme.md](https://github.com/Zardozz/FixedHeaderTableLayout/blob/master/README.md) Doc says under features

> Support for API 16 upwards

I cannot remember why I set it for API 16 upwards, but probably because I use some API that is only in API 16 and upwards.